# prepareForSegue method in iphone

Tags: iphone, uistoryboardsegue

When I click a button web service is called using Soap and then i parse the data using nsxml parser in the firstviewcontroller class. Now i have a secondviewcontroller class where i need to display the parsed data from the firstviewcontroller class.. I have added a segue to connect the button (in the firstviewcontrolller, same button as i mentioned) and the seconviewcontroller.  After completing the code when i click the button a new screen comes but the data which i was displaying is not there.When i go back using the navigationcontroller back button and again click the button (on the firstviewcontroller) , now the data is displayed..  Why it is not being displayed for the first time whenever i run the program?   In my opinion prepareForSegue method is called before the web service call and parsing, if it is so then what is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having the segue happen as soon as you hit the button, call `performSegueWithIdentifier` after your web service call is done parsing.  Alternatively, you can have your second view controller reload its data when the web service call is done parsing

Comment: I tried to use  performSegueWithIdentifier but it didn't help because   the prepareforsegue method is called just after the -(ibaction)on click:(id) sender method finishes executing.After that method i have didReceiveResponse,didReceiveData,didFailWithError,connectionDidFinishLoading methods. after these methods i have the delegate methods for nsxml parsing and then i have the prepareforsegue method.